# can I update the table, which is selected in cursor? in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am writing a procedure for mysql database, here is the procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS accidents.task_51_proce;
CREATE PROCEDURE accidents.`task_51_proce`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE v_mine INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_date DATETIME;
  DECLARE v_lat INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_lng INTEGER;

DECLARE weather_cursor CURSOR FOR select mine_id, accident_dt, lat, lng
                              from test_1
                              where accident_dt between STR_TO_DATE('1/1/2010', '%m/%d/%Y') and
                              STR_TO_DATE('1/2/2010', '%m/%d/%Y');
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
OPEN weather_cursor;

get_update: LOOP

    FETCH weather_cursor INTO v_mine, v_date, v_lat, v_lng; 

    IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE get_update;
    END IF;
    UPDATE test_1
    set tmin = (
                SELECT tmin
                FROM test_2
                WHERE Longitude_MAX <= v_lng and 
                Longitude_MIN >= v_lng and 
                Latitude_MAX <=  v_lat and  
                Latitude_MIN >= v_lat and  
                STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = STR_TO_DATE(v_date, '%m/%d/%Y')); 

END LOOP get_update;
CLOSE weather_cursor;
END;
```

the cursor query return only 51 records in very small time, but when I run the procedure it executes for a very long time and not complete.

I think there is some thing like mutating table (oracle concept) in this code, I am updating the same table which is used in cursor select.

regards:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to insert the results in a temp table rather than using cursor.

Create the temp table in the beginning, insert from select the required data and go through the table updating source table.